# Discord.js random caps

Tags: discord.js

I've been trying to add some more fun commands to my Discord bot and one of those commands is that the user can type a command with a text and that the bot will put that text in random caps.
I have been trying to get it to work for a while now, but can only get it to work when the text is already coded in. The randomization itself does work

Example of the command:

User: +random text here

Bot: TeXt HeRe

The code I have so far is

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "random",
    category: "fun",
    description: "Sends random caps text back",
    usage: "+random <text>",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

        //Checks if there is something to randomize
        if (!args[0]) return message.reply("Please also provide text to randomize");

        //Text needs to be in a const here
        const str = "text the user has submitted";

        //Gets the randomized text and sends it
        const randified = randify(str);
        message.channel.send(randified);

        //Randomizes the text
        function randify(string) {
            const arr = string.toLowerCase().split("");
            arr.forEach((e, i, a) => (Math.random() > .4) ? a[i] = e.toUpperCase() : e);
            return arr.join("");
        };
    }
```

as you can see I currently need to have the text in a const and I have not been albe to get it to work without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, it uses `map` instead of `forEach` as it will return an array of the characters which can then be joined.

```
const randified = text
  .split('')
  .map(char => Math.random() > 0.5 ? char.toUpperCase() : char.toLowerCase())
  .join('')
```

Or if you want it in a separate function:

```
function randify(input) {
  return input
    .split('')
    .map(char => Math.random() > 0.5 ? char.toUpperCase() : char.toLowerCase())
    .join('')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but when I try and use the first part (the const one) I get the error that 'text' does not exist

Comment: Well yeah, that's just a placeholder variable I used. Replace it with your variable with the text you want to change.